# Why is the ActionPerformed performed several times?

Tags: java, swing, enums, combobox, jbutton

I have a small issue and I'm sure it's a stupid mistake but here I go.

I have a GUI containing amongst other objects a JComboBox and a JButton.
The ComboBox (called orderTypeChoices in my code) contains the names of objects in an "enum" called OrderType.
This is my enum :

```
public enum OrderType {
BUILD_SCREENING_CENTER,
INCREASE_TAXES,
RESEARCH_MEDICINE,
RESEARCH_VACCINE
```

}

In my code, there is a method called executeOrder that executes other code, depending on the OrderType. I'm pretty much sure the error isn't here.
The context is that I need to check in the JComboBox which item is selected, so when I click on the button, the executeOrder will use what's selected as Item.

```
ActionListener actionListener = new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            String orderName = (String) cloudPandemic.orderTypeChoices.getSelectedItem();
            for (OrderType orderType : OrderType.values()) {
                if (orderType.name().equals(orderName)) {
                    System.out.println(orderType.name());
                    cloudPandemic.executeButton.addActionListener(e1 -> cloudPandemic.simulation.executeOrder(OrderType.valueOf(orderName)));
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    };
    this.cloudPandemic.orderTypeChoices.addActionListener(actionListener);
```

So I added 2 ActionListeners (one to the ComboBox and the other to the Button). I store in a String the String name of the Item and check in my enum if one of the objects in it matches namewise. If it does, I add an ActionListener to the button, in which I use the method executeOrder. However, I've noticed that it tends to accumulate : If I choose at first one Item, it'll work, if I choose another Item, it'll execute on both this item and the first item i've chosen, etc.

I was wondering if I missed something, because I don't see why the ActionPerformed is executing past Actions.

Thanks in advance,
Fares.

Comment: I guess you need to remove previously added listener in case of (!order Type.name().equals(orderName)) else block.

Comment: @Oleksandr Oh, great idea. I'll try that right now. But we'd remove the Button's listener, right?

Comment: As far as I understand you want to have different button actions depending on selected combobox item. So I wouldn't add Listener to ComboBox as you did. I would add 1 listener to Button and then just get ComboBox currently selected item (getSelectedItem) inside that Action. If I had simple compilable example we could save time discussing the issue :).

Comment: @Oleksandr *"If I had simple compilable example.."* Note that `[mre]` is a magic link that expands to [mre].

Comment: @Andrew Thompson Thank you for the point.